# Установка переменных в bash(Linux) из PHP

Tags: php, linux, golang

Вот хочу запустить программу написанную на go, что бы это сделать нужно установить значения переменным GOPATH и GOROOT командой export. Только вот как это сделать через system в PHP? Как я понял это переменная из окружения bash, а я вызываю просто команду операционной системы. Пробовал system("bash export GOROOT=mypatch"), и "sh export GOROOT=mypatch", результата нет.

Comment: Запустить или скомпилить?

Answer (score 2):

Установить переменные окружения в РНР гораздо проще, это делается функцией `putenv()`

```
putenv("GOROOT=mypatch");
```

Ты же своими командами запускаешь новые командные оболочки, для которых и устанавливаешь переменные.